# python fully qualified domain name

Tags: python, fqdn

I am using Python 3.7 socket to get the FQDN, fully qualified domain name.
It works for some, e.g.

```py
socket.getfqdn('indiana.edu')
'www.indiana.edu'
```

and doesn't work for others, e.g.

```py
socket.getfqdn('google.com')
'lga34s18-in-f14.1e100.net'
```

Using lga34s18-in-f14.1e100.net in the browser gives the 404 error, url not found.

Ok, google.com is just one example. Here is another one:

```py
socket.getfqdn('www.finastra.com')
'ec2-52-51-237-24.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com'
```

And using url 'ec2-52-51-237-24.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com' doesn't work, obviously. So they host their website on AWS, but why does socket return it as the FQDM, isn't 'finastra.com' the FQDM?

Comment: Related reading: https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/174717?hl=en

Comment: What are you trying to do? `google.com` is fully qualified, why push that into `getfqdn`? `getfqdn` is probably meant to resolve local names, i.e., `getfqdn("router') == "gateway.mynetwork"`.

Comment: Ok, a fair question. What i'm trying to do is to resolve some ip addresses I have to FQDN . I can't share those addresses, all I can say that they are supposed to resolve to some "simple" domain names, like google.com or finastra.com, but resolve to something similar to what I get for these two. Once it happened to those ip's, I decided to try  google.com or finastra.com and discovered that they also produce some funny FQDNs. I hope this explains what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

`socket.getfqdn()` [calls `socket.gethostbyaddr()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6eb9619c88612565b424be14196a8adae6d51978/Lib/socket.py#L791) (as stated [in docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.getfqdn)) to resolve the address. `socket.gethostbyaddr()` will issue a type A DNS request (if the domain is not on your hosts file) which will resolve to whatever the DNS of `google.com` or `www.finastra.com` is configured.

> Using lga34s18-in-f14.1e100.net in the browser gives the 404 error, url not found.

This is because your browser sends a [Host header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.23) which is filled with the hostname from the URL. A single webserver can serve content from different hosts. For example, the following request won't return a *404 Not Found*:

```
curl ec2-52-51-237-24.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com -H 'Host: www.finastra.com'
```

Removing `-H 'Host: www.finastra.com'` will cause the request to issue `Host: ec2-52-51-237-24.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com` header and return *404 Not Found*.